# Cross-compile on Centos 7 for Centos 6 system

Tags: cross-compiling, centos7, centos6, glibc

I am building a binary `FOO` on Centos 7 (uses `glibc 2.14`) and I want it to run on Centos 6 (only has `glibc 2.12`)

If I install `glibc 2.14` in parallel on the Centos 6 system:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5#299665

then what do I need to do to run `FOO` and use `glibc 2.14` .so libraries ?

Does setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` help ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to install `mock` from EPEL and build in a CentOS 6 chroot.  This assumes that you have already packaged your software as an RPM package.

It is theoretically possible to unpack the glibc RPMs into a new directory tree (not `/`) and run the compiler and linker in such a way that these files are used instead of the system glibc.  However, I don't think CentOS 7 toolchain was built with sysroot support, so this is a bit tricky.  You could build glibc from source and see what compiler and linker invocations it uses because it has the same problem (programs like `localedef` need to be compiled against the just-built glibc, not the already installed one).

Comment: Thanks. Sounds interesting. I've since decided to abandon this idea.